# Angular 7 Unit testing Observable subscribe call

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I've a `GeoLocationService` in my angular application like this.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class GeoLocationService {
  coordinates: any;

  constructor() {}

  public getPosition(): Observable<Position> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((pos: Position) => {
        observer.next(pos);
      }),
        () => {
          console.log("Position is not available");
        },
        {
          enableHighAccuracy: true
        };
    });
  }
}
```

I want to unit test this service to ensure that the `getPosition()` function returns me a working `Observable`. Here's how my test looks like.

```
import { TestBed, fakeAsync } from "@angular/core/testing";

import { GeoLocationService } from "./geo-location.service";
import { take } from "rxjs/operators";

describe("GeoLocationService", () => {
  let service: GeoLocationService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [GeoLocationService]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(GeoLocationService);
  });


  it("should get observable value", fakeAsync((done: DoneFn) => {
    service
      .getPosition()
      .subscribe(value => {
        expect(value.coords).not.toBeUndefined();
        expect(value.coords).not.toBeNaN();
        expect(value.coords).not.toBeNull();
        done();
      });
  }));
});
```

What happens here is that once I run the test the test is successful ( this is because the `subscribe` block inside the test is not run yet). On the `chrome browser window` that opens ( for viewing test results in karma ), I select `Allow` for the application to find my location, it is at this moment the `subscribe` block runs but by that time the `it` spec has already finished due to this reason I get a `console error` saying.

`Uncaught Error: 'expect' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out`.

I don't know what is the recommended way to perform this test.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get it working using the following code.

```
  it("should get current user coordinates", (done: DoneFn) => {
    let position: any;
    service.getPosition().subscribe(value => {
      position = value;
      expect(position.coords).not.toBeUndefined();
      expect(position.coords).not.toBeNaN();
      expect(position.coords).not.toBeNull();
      done();
    });
  });
```

For this the test waits until you `Allow` the browser window to get your location. If you wait for too long, it will throw a timeOut error. Good enough for me to test what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tick()` which fakes the test into being synchronous-ish :-)

```
  it("should get observable value", fakeAsync((done: DoneFn) => {
    let matchValue = {coords: null};
    service
      .getPosition()
      .subscribe(value => {
        matchValue = value;
      });
      tick(2000); // whatever fits your needs
      expect(matchValue.coords).not.toBeUndefined();
      expect(matchValue.coords).not.toBeNaN();
      expect(matchValue.coords).not.toBeNull();
      done();
  }));
```

Comment: This way, also, we wouldn't need the `done` callback.

Comment: the `tick` is not waiting, I am not sure what is the reason. Due to this reason `matchValue.coords` remian `null` causing the test to fail, not sure why its not waiting

Comment: How long did you choose the tick timeout?

Comment: I made it 5000 also, doesn't work. I did manage to solve it. posted answer below